# How to invoke mulitple dialogs and associate them wth a user thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, win32gui

I am developing an application which allows multiple Modal dialogs to be opened simultaneous. I have been experiencing an issue as to whenever I close the first dialog, it closes without error and call doesn't back to the callee until I close the second dialog which is defeating the purpose what I have to achieve.

Sample code:

```
Class A
{
    func1()
    {
        ....
        DOModal()
        ....//some processing
    }

Class B
{
    func2()
    {
        ...
        doModal()
    }
}
```

I tried with creating a user thread and event mechanism by associating it with the dialog but what is happening is it's actually not letting me to open the another dialog until I respond. I still want the execution to happen as it is.

My application is a single threaded environment.

Comment: How are the calls to `A.func1()` and `B.func2()` related to each other?  Is `func1()` called first? Is `func2()` called while `func1()` is still running? Please provide a more complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

DoModal dialog will allow you to launch only one at a time for each thread. Instead, you can try [*create*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd.aspx) and *show* the dialog with the parameters *nIDTemplate* as the ID of dialog and *pParentWnd* as parent window. Here you will not be required to create the multiple threads.

Comment: Requirements says to have a Modal dialog not the modaless .